# How can i fix the haskell hugs error Instance of Integral Bool required for definition of

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, hugs

I am writing a haskell module for hugs and i get the error shown in the title.

What does this mean and how do i fix this?

the code in question is the second line

```
    and1 :: [Bool] -> Bool
    and1 [] = True
```

This is the first part of the module after the module declaration itself.

Answer (score 2):

The error says that you're trying to use a `Bool` as an integral, a typeclass allowing most of the operations you'd expect to be on `Integer`. However, the code you've posted is error free.

Without the rest of the code this is impossible to diagonose. But did you perhaps add a space between and and 1? Eg `and 1 [] = True`